# single or multiple databases advice needed

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I know there are a few of these posts, but not in relation to my specific quandary.

I've always gone the 'per user' SQL Server DB rather than 'one DB for all' because:

a) I thought speed wise it's better for a lite user to only work within their small DB rather than all users being possibly affected by a few big users (surely searching a few hundred rows each time is better than searching through thousands of rows all the time).

b) If a server has too many DBs (very wishful thinking) then I can put the next lot of users on a 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc server.

c) If a user no longer wishes to use my app or needs it restoring to a backup then I just bin/or restore their specific DB and don't affect anybody else.

My problem is that my next pet project involves pupils potentially competing against pupils in other schools and also showing a league table of schools so I just keep thinking a per school DB is going to be really messy compared to everybody in one DB.  Would you agree?

My fear of one DB is that later down the line there might be potentially 500 schools (again wishful thinking) with on average 300 pupils in each school which is a lot of pupil logins and results to manage in one DB - without it being lumpy.

Anybody had similar problems and overcome them?

Thanks

Comment: If all of the DB's are competing with the same resources (CPU, Memory, etc) or are on the same instance, thus competing for other resources like tempdb, then creating additional databases (especially in the quantities you speak of) doesn't provide any benefit that i can see. It would be, however, a nightmare to manage (backups, restores, index maintenance, dbcc operations, etc). VLDB, or very large databases, aren't uncommon so your fear may simply be fearing what you don't know, or perhaps assuming problems before they arise. Don't over optimize based on fears.

Comment: To add to scsimon's answer,  "surely searching a few hundred rows each time is better than searching through thousands of rows all the time" --> Proper indexing on the table + optimizing your queries should negate this. Also, optimizing your queries and adding indexes should be more manageable on one database.

Comment: Hi scsimon/randi  thank you for the prompt and informed replies.  When it comes to scale and concurrent user demand with a big db is it basically increasing the power (CPU, memory) of the server??

Comment: It is very much the fear of the unknown!! :)

Comment: I mean if the data is the same, the connections are the same, the batches are the same, then it should not matter if it is in one database or multiple. The only thing that changes is blocking, depending on if you are separating the schools via tables in the same database, or creating a db for each school. Updates, inserts and deletes will be a big factor here

Comment: I was thinking of a schools table that will hold the id, name, etc of the schools that are users.  This id would then be part of the pupils table to differentiate which pupils are in which schools.  When doing league tables I can then do a select count/group on the pupils to see which schools are doing the best.  My biggie is that the pupils table could potentially contain 150,000 pupil rows (500 schools x 300 pupils)

Comment: Having it all in one db is the only way that I could think would be the best and cleanest way to enable pupils from different schools to compete with each other and for me to store their results as they compete.

Comment: The rows should not matter, if you have to do a count of all the pupils of all the schools, it would be the same in one or many databases. The school table with school id is a good idea.

Comment: Alternatively I can only think that there would be an all schools DB for posting overall scores per school (overhead of connecting to the all schools db as well as the user db when doing updates) and when doing pupil v pupil from diff schools it would have to be a lot of connecting to diff dbs to update their results in their db.  SQL Server lets me do db.dbo.table, but isn't this a lot heavier than just doing it all through one db connection?

Comment: I've done a db before that has an all schools table to store 17,000 school basic info recs and then had another user schools table to store the school info recs of the schools that actually use my web app (makes the auto-complete a lot faster) and then a db per school to keep all of the school pupils, results, etc but this is the first time it looks like I've got to keep everything in one DB and I'm fearful :)

Comment: Do you mean cross database queries?  That should not be an issue, see here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/692/sql-server-2008-cross-database-performance-on-same-physical-machine-and-server. The only thing I could think of is when the Collations don't match, but that should not be a lot of overhead.

Comment: I like the security blanket of per user db, but I just can't think of a cleaner way of keeping on top of pupil v pupil challenges data  and overall school data that a single db would give me.

Comment: I just don't want the 1000s of rows to slowdown the overall accessing/updating of it.  Fear again - I suppose.

Comment: That is where indexing comes into play, and 1000's of rows should not be an issue unless you have too many columns or too much LOB data. The total data read would be the same, just spread out over more databases. You can totally opt for a database per school however, you are just going to be the person responsible for managing it. If you prefer multiple databases, that is 100% possible, it will just be more work IMHO.

Comment: *is it basically increasing the power (CPU, memory) of the server* this is one potential solution. But proper troubleshooting is where i'd start (indexes, query tuning, etc). Regarding seperating the schools, you could give them all their own [schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server) if their tables aren't going to be identical. If they are then manage permissions with [row level security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017) or something.

Comment: I honestly don't think you should be this worried about storing these clients in the same DB. It's likely that if you structure these tables in a way that leads by say a ShoolID and have that lead your clustering key SQL server won't have to comb through all your data to get to the school you'd like. It will also make maintanace a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

How much data are you dealing with? 500 schools with 300 students in each is not a lot of data for SQL Server to deal with if you design the tables well. As other users have mentioned in the comments, a few indexes on the right columns and you should be fine. SQL Server can happily run terabytes of data without working too hard.

The management of multiple databases is also much harder than it looks. A few examples:

1. Deploying schema changes to multiple databases when you upgrade your application
2. Backups for multiple databases - location, times, restore time, etc.
3. Running other maintenance tasks (checkdb) for multiple databases

The one point you mentioned that is harder is if restoring or deleting the data for a particular school is an important requirement. It is much harder to restore/delete data for 1 school if they are all in the same database, and that reason might be enough to mean you should split the data.

My general rule is if it's the same app then you should start designing it in 1 database until you have a reason to split it.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for tips.  Yes, it's one web app to be used by multiple users/schools.  I've just never done all in one db before and I think this is where the trepidation is coming from.  In my previous projects, I've had a fallback that if there seemed to be too many dbs/users on the server then I just point user #400 to server #2 and then it continues - but like you say iterating a db update to all dbs is fun :)

Comment: It does take away the option of scaling out, but I would be very surprised if you couldn't scale up to meet demand.